# Pine scripts (tradingview) convert python

Tags: python, pine-script

I have two pine scripts (tradingview). How can I the script to Pandas python or with help talib library convert and how can man ‘pds’ calculate. I donot need The plot.
I well by thankful if some help

````
wapScore(pds) =>
    mean = sum(volume*close,pds)/sum(volume,pds)
    vwapsd = sqrt(sma(pow(close-mean, 2), pds) )
    (close-mean)/vwapsd

plot(vwapScore(48),title="ZVWAP2-2",color=#ffe0b2, linewidth=2,transp=0.75)
plot(vwapScore(199),title="ZVWAP2-2",color=#cfb9ff, linewidth=2,style=circles,transp=0.75)
plot(vwapScore(484),title="ZVWAP2-3",color=#ffe0b2, linewidth=2,style=circles,transp=0.75)

 =============================================================

study("VWAP", overlay=true)
typicalPrice = (high + low + close) / 3
typicalPriceVolume = typicalPrice * volume

cumulativePeriod1 = input(48, "Period")
cumulativeTypicalPriceVolume1 = sum(typicalPriceVolume, cumulativePeriod1)
cumulativeVolume1 = sum(volume, cumulativePeriod1)
vwapValue1 = cumulativeTypicalPriceVolume1 / cumulativeVolume1
plot(vwapValue1,color=#b2b5be,style=circles)```
````

Answer (score 1):

df['typicalPrice'] = (df['high'] + df['low'] + df['close']) / 3

df['typicalPriceVolume'] = df['typicalPrice'] * df['volume']

df['cumulativeTypicalPriceVolume1'] = df['typicalPriceVolume'].rolling(48).sum()

df['cumulativeVolume1'] = df['volume'].rolling(48).sum()

df['vwapValue1'] = df['cumulativeTypicalPriceVolume1']/df['cumulativeVolume1']

this code can be use for the second pine script code